# Regex pattern to parse search terms with search syntax

Tags: regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I am writing a search term parser to classify search tokens for later post-processing. So far I have this pattern:

`/([+])?([\-])?(\"([^\"]+)?\"?|([^\\s]+)?|([^*]+)?)([\\s])?/`

Taking a sample search string such as:

`c++ +this -only this* +"is a very" "complex example"`

I would like to get the following result

```
G1   G2    G3                 G4                G5     G6   G7
           c++                                  c++         [space]
+          +this                                this        [space]
     -     -only                                only        [space]
           this*                                this   *    [space]
+          "is a very"        is a very                     [space]
           "complex example"  complex example               [space]
```

What I get is almost like above matches but the `this*` term, which appears in group 5 as `this*`.

I know the part `... ([^\\s]+)?|([^*]+)?) ...` is not correct but I have no better idea how to reformulate it. I have tried several ways but seem not to find a a good solution by swapping the sub-patterns, etc. 
I would be happy if someone could give me a few hints on how to solve this and probably make the search term matching part a bit more effective.

This is my test script:

```
<?php
$s = "c++ +this -only this* +\"is a very\" \"complex example\"";
$rc = preg_match_all(
        "/([+])?([\-])?(\"([^\"]+)?\"?|([^\\s]+)?|([^*]+)?)([\\s])?/",
    $s,
    $m);

print_r($m);
?>
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: But there isn't a group 4 in this https://regex101.com/r/lZ6hS8/1 ?

Comment: may i know what are you trying to achieve with those groups? Please write the group contents in a single line.

Comment: @Avinash: I use the groups to classify the search tokens (actually the group IDs are used to set a few bits, such as if tokens are include or exlude terms, phrases or wildcard terms. The code is part of a c++ program I use for a spellchecker, for example.

Comment: you should get some idea from this https://regex101.com/r/fM9gS2/3 regex

Comment: @Avinash: Thanks for the input! Definetely something to experiment with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you differentiate between G1 and G2. Here is a working pattern:

```
([-+]?)("([^"]+)"|([^\s*]+)(\*?))(\s)?
```

The problem with your pattern was that you were using `([^\\s]+)?|([^*]+)?)`. Since `test*` would satisfy the first condition from the choices, second option is never compared.

---

The PHP implementation would be:

```
$re = "~([-+]?)(\"([^\"]+)\"|([^\\s*]+)(\\*?))(\\s)?~";
$str = "c++ +this -only this* +\"is a very\" \"complex example\"";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

The downside of using this pattern would be having a blank G5 (G6 in your table) for every word. You may use a lookahead for the corner case, but I wouldn't worry too much over it.

Comment: G1 are exclude terms, G2 are include terms. G5 is the space at the end of the token, which is fine. Reason is that I carry a bitset that reflects each token property. One little question: what would I had to change if I would like to capture not only the asterisk appended to a term (as in G5) but the entire term 'this*'?